# Deleted /Developer/Library

Tags: macos

How can I download it again? All the developer tools I'm using (Xcode, eclipse, command line tools) are fully functional, but I want to use `/Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools`, which, of course, is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no longer necessary. If you want to delete the developer tools now, you just delete the XCode application.

Comment: Thanks! What other files in your /Developer/Library am I likely missing?

Comment: `/Developer/Library` is no longer used under Xcode 4.3. The files which used to be there have all been moved into the Xcode application bundle

Comment: What other files exist in `/Developer/Library` on which other applications depend?

Comment: There shouldn't be any. That directory was only intended for use by Apple's developer tools.