# inApp Purchase Problems in iOS7

Tags: ios7, xcode5, storekit

I get this error in my debug when I run my app in any iOS 7 simulator.

```
Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xf830e80 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/SocialFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xc12c610 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MusicLibrary.axbundle> (not loaded)
Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xf834600 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/StoreKitFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xc1478d0 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xb55b7c0 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/GeoServices.axbundle> (not loaded)
```

It does not happen in when  I test on the iOS 6 simulator.

In particular it seems to prevent storekit from returning any products in the simulator or devices.

Comment: Try this one
> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345263/cannot-find-executable-for-cfbundle-cfplugin-error

Comment: Unfortunately > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929250/deleted-developer-library but I am reinstalling xcode to see if that helps

Comment: And a reinstall of Xcode didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after many reinstallations and checkbox unchecking. 
I found that is was me who needed correcting.

I never figured out how to link the proper executable but the issue only affected the iOS 7.0 simulator. On actual devices everything performed as expected.

Comment: @"I never figured out how to link the proper executable" can you elaborate? What specifically fixed the issue for you?

Comment: Ack, you know you're an Obj-C developer when muscle memory puts @ before quotes.

Comment: @chris-wagner I never found anything to fix the issue and noticed that all of the apple developer forum posts seemed to have died out. Eventually it seemed that it was only effecting the simulator and not the actual device. I still get those errors it just seems everyone has settled on ignoring them until apple fixes it.  So clarify I did nothing to fix the issues and making sure i was logged in with a test account on my iOS 7 device fixed my storekit issue.

Comment: Ok thanks for the response. I think this is related to some AddressBook crashes I have been experiencing only in the simulator. It crashes on some Accessibility framework issue. Works fine on the device though.